# Why uniform_int_distribution with char template parameter is not allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standards

[C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) in it's paragraph 26.5.1.1 states the following:

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> e) that has a template type parameter named IntType is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.
>
> f) that has a template type parameter named UIntType is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long` .

So

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<char> r;
```

may cause UB, as well as the same thing with unsigned char, int8_t and uint8_t.

GNU compilers allow to instantiate `uniform_int_distribution` with `char` and the above code works well. But Microsoft [rightfully](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/856484/std-uniform-int-distribution-does-not-like-char) [claims](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793763):

> We're trying to help user code stay out of the realm of undefined behavior by being strict instead of permissive.

Visual studio does not compile the code, failing with errors:

```
error C2338: invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t>' being compiled
```

What is the rationale behind these limitations? Will the Committee allow to instantiate  `uniform_int_distribution` with single-byte types in the future versions of the language?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to, since you can still make a distribution between 0 and 255.

Comment: I would guess a finite enumerated list of types keeps testing easier.  `char` is tricky because it can be either signed or unsigned, and IIRC can have other quirks.  `int8_t` need nit be a type at all.  So I guess conservative specs is the only reason.

Comment: @Yakk But in this case, `signed char` and `unsigned char` should be allowed... Maybe there is some kind of answers in the proposal.